# See if the intersection of regular expressions is empty using FAdo

Tags: python, regex, fsm, formal-languages, nfa

I'm interested in seeing if there's any overlap between two regular expressions. I thought the best way is to convert the regular expressions to nondeterministic finite automata and then see if the intersection of those NFAs is empty.

I see this FAdo Python package here: https://pypi.org/project/FAdo/

And the documentation: https://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~rvr/FAdo.pdf

Here is my function:

```
from FAdo import reex

def no_overlap(a, b):
    n1 = reex.str2regexp(a).toNFA()
    n2 = reex.str2regexp(b).toNFA()
    c = n1.conjunction(n2)
    return _______

assert no_overlap('(a)*', '(b)*')
```

But I can't figure out what to put in the blank to figure out if `c` is empty. I'm at a loss - thanks for your help!

Comment: Thank you - I've added the import statement plus an assertion at the end that should have the behavior I'm expecting, but I'm not sure what to put in the blank. I was hoping for someone with a better understanding of finite state machines to offer any suggestions, but totally understand if that is out of scope for StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, one more question: what exactly does an overlap mean in an NFA?

Comment: Sorry, I mean intersection. Looking to accept states that are accepted by both of the automata. If the intersection is empty (there are no states that are accepted by both of the automata), then the regular expressions have no overlap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this doesn't perfectly answer the original question, but I ended up solving my problem (computing the intersection of two regular expressions) using the greenery library: https://github.com/qntm/greenery